# Asymptotic comparison of functions

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I want to compare following functions asymptotically and then arrange them in the ascending order. Also requested is a proper explanation 
lg((√n)!), lg(SquareRoot(n!)), SquareRootlg(n!), (lg(√n))!, (SquareRoot(lg n))!, SquareRoot(lg n)!

Comment: well i know that log (n!) is O(nlogn) so i can check that the first three would arranged as SqRt(Log(n!)) Log(SqRt(n)!) log(SqRt(n!)) but cant compare the next three with these...please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wonder about *"general solution"* and you follow a lot into asymptotic functions comparisons. Here is what I recommend :

Use [limit definition of BigO notation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/which-definition-of-asymptotic-growth-rate-should-we-teach), once you know:

```
f(n) = O(g(n)) iff limit (n approaches +inf) f(n)/g(n) exists and is not +inf
```

You can use [Computer Algebra System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system), for example opensource [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), here is in [Maxima documentation about limits](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_17.html) .

So, checking `lg(n)*lg(n) = O(sqrt(n))` can be dane is checking limit of `(lg(n)lg(n))/sqrt(n)` :

```
(%i1) limit( (log(n)^2) / (sqrt(n)), n, inf);
(%o1)                                  0
```

If you like, longer, more descriptive notation :

```
(%i1) f(n) := log(n)^2 ;
                                           2
(%o1)                           f(n) := log (n)
(%i2) g(n) := sqrt(n) ;
(%o2)                           g(n) := sqrt(n)
(%i3) limit(f(n)/g(n), n, inf);
(%o3)                                  0
```